# When is a thermodynamic system isobaric?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, gas, reversibility

I came across a problem where a piston and gas arrangement was present and it was heated, so if the piston is free to move we call it isobaric. But is it only true if it is quasi static (reversible process) or also for a normal irreversible process, and if not will that process be some polytropic process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Isobaric* means the pressure of the *system* remains constant during the process. This requires a mechanism such as the movable piston to allow the volume to expand or contract as needed to maintain constant pressure. Just running a process in a cylinder/piston arrangement does not guarantee it is isobaric, the motion of the piston should be low enough to allow for the equalization of pressures between the system and the surroundings.

The cylinder/piston arrangement is mostly used as a thought experiment when learning thermodynamics in order to visualize a process that represents the integration paths we use. In homework problems we typically assume that a process conducted in a cylinder with a piston is isobaric, *unless* the problem gives hints that it is not.

Answer (score 3):

A reversible isobaric process is one in which the system pressure is constant throughout the system and always in equilibrium with the constant external pressure.

An irreversible isobaric process is one in which the system pressure varies spatially  within the system and only equals the constant external pressure at the boundary (per Newton’s third law).

Generally the difference between the reversible and irreversible constant pressure process is the reversible process is carried out very slowly (quasi-statically) whereas the irreversible process is carried out quickly. An example of the latter is the rapid heating of a gas causing the piston to rise quickly against constant external atmospheric pressure.

Hope this helps.